# Why my cron job laravel 5.3 not working on localhost?

Tags: php, laravel, cron, laravel-5.3

I am using windows.

My code on `\app\Console\Kernel.php` is like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Console;

use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    protected $commands = [
        Commands\CustomCommand::class,
    ];

    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->command('custom:command')
                 ->everyMinute();
    }

    protected function commands()
    {
        require base_path('routes/console.php');
    }
}
```

My code on `\app\Console\Commands\CustomCommand.php` is like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use DB;

class CustomCommand extends Command
{
    protected $signature = 'custom:command';

    protected $description = 'test cron job to update status on table order';

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        $id = 1;
        DB::table('orders')
          ->where('id', $id)
          ->update(['status' => 2, 'canceled_at' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s")]);
    }
}
```

I run `php artisan list` to see my cron job

After find my cron job (custom:command), then I run my cron job with like this : `php artisan custom:command`

It's successful update status = 2. After that I change the status manually again become 1, and then I wait one minute, it does not update status again

Is there anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

You should also set cron on your local web server to run cron jobs.

Answer (score 0):

How you change the status manually?
You change it in the database?
maybe the cron is running but 'id' int the database is equal to '2' and maybe this is why you dont see any change!

If you look for a better way to check if the Cron job is working

just add Log that will wroth to the log file

```
 public function handle()
{
    Log::info('Cron job working'); // you can also print variables
    $id = 1;
    DB::table('orders')
      ->where('id', $id)
      ->update(['status' => 2, 'canceled_at' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s")]);
}
```

Don't forget to had the Log to your source:

```
namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use DB;
use Log; // Here

class CustomCommand extends Command
```